# How to find duplicates from sql database using LINQ in c#

Tags: c#, windows, linq, duplicates

I have a method which will return duplicate records from database using sql command. The code is:

```
 public bool RecordExists(string name)
   {
       OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select count(*) from Demographics where thal_Id = '" + txtPtntSmpl.Text + "'", con);
       int recordCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
       cn.Close();
       return recordCount > 0;
   }
```

According to this ,If I call this method in textbox leave event I will raise an error while duplicate records occurs from database. Now I want the **same operation by using linq**. Please anyone help me. Thanking you

Comment: -1 because question has *nothing* to do with duplicates. Please be precise so that the question will be useful to others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Linq to SQL, having `dc` as your data context, it should look smth like this:

```
public bool RecordExists(string id)
{
    return dc.Demographics.Any(d => d.thal_Id == id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a List of Demographic and you want to see how many match a certain text value, try something like this:

```
 public bool RecordExists(string name)
   {
       List<Demographic> demographics = PopulateList();

       return demographics.Count(d => d.thal_Id == name) > 0;
   }
```

Comment: Iam not getting PopulateList method. what is that means.. and I tried as 
  public bool RecordExists(string name)
       {
           List<cstmr> demographics = from ins in cstDC.demographics where ins.Name == name select ins;

           return demographics.Count(d => d.cst_Name == name) > 1;
       }

in this case Iam getting error as

Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<slsandPchsLib.cstmr>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<slsandPchsLib.cstmr>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast

Comment: To use LINQ, you have to have a List or Enumerable to compare against.  If you're wanting the full code to populate the list, there are a number of options, ORMs, custom DTOs, etc. etc.  Good luck.